# Color Management with a Family of Curves

Tags: tables, color, expansion, pgfplotstable, foreach

I am struggling with following fairly simple looking problem of plotting a family of curves.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\pgfplotstableread{
1   1
2   4
3   9
4   16
5   25
}\dataQuad

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    legend pos=north west,
    domain=0:5,
    xlabel=${x}$,
    ylabel=${y}$]
    \foreach \y/\c in {2/black,3/green,4/red,5/brown}{%
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[color=\c,line width=1pt] {x^\y};}
        \temp
        \addlegendentryexpanded{$y=x^\y$}
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    legend pos=north west,
    domain=0:5,
    cycle list name=color,
    xlabel=${x}$,
    ylabel=${y}$]
    \addplot [smooth] table[x index=0, y index=1] {\dataQuad};
    \legend{$y=x^2$}
    \foreach \y in {3, 4, 5} {%
%       \foreach \y/\c in {3/green,4/red,5/brown}{%
        \addplot [smooth] table[x index=0, y expr=\thisrowno{0}^\y] {\dataQuad};
%           \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot [smooth] table[x index=0, y expr=\thisrowno{0}^\y] {\dataQuad};}
%           \temp
        \addlegendentryexpanded{$y=x^\y$}
    }   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to have the same result shown on the left when using a table with some math expressions. One problem is to handle the color management when uncomment the lines within second tikzpicture (by changing the *foreach*-loop). I can't get it to work. Seems to be a problem with expansion.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: this here explains what went wrong in your case. However, Jake's approach constitutes a best-practice: it relies on `cycle list` which simplifies style (color) management and avoids the issue altogether.

---

The complicated structure with `\edef` is incomplete; it is an expansion issue (as you suspected).

The problem is that `\edef` (Expanded DEFinition) attempts to expand every encountered macro. In your case, you ONLY want to expand `\y` and `\c`. Consequently, you have to protect every other encountered macro. In your case, the protection is missing for `\thisrowno` and `\dataQuad`. The "protection" is done by prefixing the macros-to-protect by `\noexpand`.

Taking it together, one arrives at

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\pgfplotstableread{
1   1
2   4
3   9
4   16
5   25
}\dataQuad

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    legend pos=north west,
    domain=0:5,
    xlabel=${x}$,
    ylabel=${y}$]
    \foreach \y/\c in {2/black,3/green,4/red,5/brown}{%
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[color=\c,line width=1pt] {x^\y};}
        \temp
        \addlegendentryexpanded{$y=x^\y$}
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    legend pos=north west,
    domain=0:5,
    cycle list name=color,
    xlabel=${x}$,
    ylabel=${y}$]
    \addplot [smooth] table[x index=0, y index=1] {\dataQuad};
    \legend{$y=x^2$}
    \foreach \y/\c in {3/green,4/red,5/brown}{%
         \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot [color=\c,smooth] table[x index=0, y expr=\noexpand\thisrowno{0}^\y] {\noexpand\dataQuad};}
         \temp
        \addlegendentryexpanded{$y=x^\y$}
    }   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Jake It is good to notice that the number of list entries in 'cycle list' do not necessarily need to match the number of loop entries.

Answer (score 4):

For applications like this, PGFPlots provides its own looping macro that expands and executes the plot commands at the right time:

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{<list>}{ <code, with #1 the current list value> }
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\pgfplotstableread{
1   1
2   4
3   9
4   16
5   25
}\dataQuad

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    legend pos=north west,
    domain=0:5,
    cycle list={black, green, red, brown},
    xlabel=${x}$,
    ylabel=${y}$
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2, 3, 4, 5}{%
        \addplot +[smooth, thick] table[x index=0, y expr=\thisrowno{0}^#1] {\dataQuad};
        \addlegendentryexpanded{$y=x^#1$}
    }   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```