# Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit

Tags: errors, loops, pgfmath, parameters

This type of error (! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number ...) arises when trying to use a predefined list for the `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`-loop. This problem is related to parameter studies where all significant parameters are put into a list, e.g. [Create Table for a Family of Curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126456/create-table-for-a-family-of-curves).

Following MWE shows the compiling error:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\pgfplotstableread{
1
2
3
4
5
}\dataQuad

\newcommand{\param}{2,3,4,5}

\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \y in \param {%
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        create col/expr={\thisrow{0}^\y}
    ]{\y}\dataQuad
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.75\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                legend pos=north west,
                domain=0:5,
                cycle list={green, red, black, purple, orange},
                xlabel=${x}$,
                ylabel=${y}$]
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,...,5}{
                    \addplot +[smooth] table [x index=0, y=#1] \dataQuad;
            }
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.75\textwidth}
        \pgfplotstabletypeset\dataQuad
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

A similar problem was discussed here [Using Macro Defined Lists in TikZ/PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17833/using-macro-defined-lists-in-tikz-pgfplots), but don't bring any solution for this particular problem.

So far I use `\newcommand{\paramA}{2}`,`\newcommand{\paramB}{3}`, and so forth and looping via `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \y in {\paramA,...,\paramE} {%`. The main drawback with this is when I need to change the number of parameters.

May someone have a more elegant way for using a predefined parameter list that can be used for every loop type like `\foreach`, `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` and `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`. Any hint is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` with a bit of `\expandafter`-trickery:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\pgfplotstableread{
1
2
3
4
5
}\dataQuad

\newcommand{\param}{2,3,4,5}

\expandafter\pgfplotsinvokeforeach\expandafter{\param}{%
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        create col/expr={\thisrow{0}^#1}
    ]{#1}\dataQuad
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.75\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                legend pos=north west,
                domain=0:5,
                cycle list={green, red, black, purple, orange},
                xlabel=${x}$,
                ylabel=${y}$]
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,...,5}{
                    \addplot +[smooth] table [x index=0, y=#1] \dataQuad;
            }
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.75\textwidth}
        \pgfplotstabletypeset\dataQuad
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```