# PGF Math: "An internal routine of the floating point unit near"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, plot

I am using this snippet:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$f(x) = x^{-1}$}
  ] 
    \addplot {x^{-1}}; % this was previously: x^2
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That worked until I changed `x^2` to `x^{-1}`. Now I am getting the following error (there are also lots of errors after it):

> PGF Math: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit near
>   '2Y1.0e0]'. (in 'x^{-1}'). \end{frame}

**Research:**

I could not find many search results except these two questions from Tex SE:

- [Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127177/package-pgf-math-error-sorry-an-internal-routine-of-the-floating-point-unit)
- [Create Table for a Family of Curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126456/create-table-for-a-family-of-curves)

Unfortunately, they seem to be unrelated since their problem is caused by a foreach construct which I don't even have in my code.

**My system**:

- MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4535 (1.40.13) (MiKTeX 2.9)
- PdfLaTeX
- Document class: Beamer

Comment: The argument of `\addplot` should be `x^(-1)`, not `x^{-1}`.  Since the resulting plot is still ugly (a value near 0 is much too large), I'll let someone with more pgfplots knowledge write a proper answer.

Comment: You need some xmin>0 or you will always get an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Bruno commented, `pgfmath` and `pgfplots` with `fpu` use parentheses for nested operations and when you provide braces, -1 passes directly to the computation bypassing the `fpu` conversion.

I would suggest using `1/x` for less grey hair and powers of `(1/x)` avoiding baldness.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=0:1,
    samples=100,
    restrict y to domain=0:10,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$f(x) = x^{-1}$}
  ] 
    \addplot+[no marks] {x^(-1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I guess I'll look up all those properties in the documentation now :)