# Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `Y'

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

When I try to compile this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{ownstyle/.style={width=4cm,height=4cm,xmin=-0.5,xmax=2,ymin=0,ymax=2,axis lines=center,axis line style={->},xlabel=t/s,ylabel=x(t),xtick={0,1},ytick={0,1}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={func(\x)=((\x)<0) * (0) + and ((\x)>=0) * (1);}]
        \begin{axis}[ownstyle]
            \addplot+[no marks,black, line width=1pt,domain=-0.5:2]{func(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

> /home/max/.test.tex.swp:12: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `Y'. The unreadable part was near 'Y'. (in '((2Y5.0e-1])<0)*(0)+and((2Y5.0e-1])>=0)*(1)').

Although the error message from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145694) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127177) is the same I can't find out how to fix this issue and it doesn't seem the same to me.

I would guess that the issue arises because addplot supplies the function with some weird input but I don't know why and how to change/fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to remove `and` from your `func`.

You might also prefer using `samples at` as in the code below, instead of just defining the domain.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{ownstyle/.style={width=4cm,height=4cm,xmin=-0.5,xmax=2,ymin=0,ymax=2,axis lines=center,axis line style={->},xlabel=t/s,ylabel=x(t),xtick={0,1},ytick={0,1}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={func(\x)=((\x)<0) * (0) + ((\x)>=0) * (1);}]
        \begin{axis}[ownstyle]
            \addplot+[no marks,black, line width=1pt,samples at={-0.5,-0.0001,0.0001,2}]{func(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked for me, is there a way to define the "samples at" property globally? I need to draw a lot graphs.

Comment: @MaxMatti Yes, you can say `\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={samples at={-0.5,-0.0001,0.0001,2}}}`, and it will apply to all `\addplot`s in the current scope. But will the same x-values be appropriate for all your plots?

Comment: Well I'll be using `\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={samples at={-0.5,-0.4,...,0.1,-0.0001,0.0001,0.1,0.2,...,0.9,0‌​.9999,1.0001,1.1,1.2‌​,...}}}` to be exact but it'll work just fine. It looks like this in the end: imgur.com/a/EA0CX