# pgfplotstable - Create an additional, calculated, column

Tags: tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

how can I get a third column "Z" in the output, where the values are e.g. x*y

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x y
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableset{% global config, for example in the preamble
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[every head row/.style={before row={
        \toprule},
                                        after row=\midrule},
    columns/x/.style={column name=x},
    columns/y/.style={column name=y},
  ]{data.dat}
\end{document}
```

This is how I would like it to look:

[image: 1]]

Comment: Have a look at e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336677 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290845. The key is to use `create on use/<some name>/.style={create col/expr={...}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at para. 4.3.2 of the [pgfplotstable manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x y
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableset{% global config, for example in the preamble
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  create on use/z/.style={
      create col/expr={\thisrow{x}*\thisrow{y}}}
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    columns={x,y,z},
    columns/x/.style={column name=x},
    columns/y/.style={column name=y},
    columns/z/.style={column name=z},
  ]{data.dat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer (+1)! i wasn't aware for this `pgfplotsdtable` possibility! apparently, i didn't read manual enough carefully :-(

Comment: @Zarko Thank you! It's the first time I use `pgfplotstable`, I have just copied the instructions from the manual and adjusted them to fit the OP's case, LOL

Comment: @Zarko, one can do amazing stuff with `pgfplotstable`, also to its feature for `pgfplots` (two examples are given in [my comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398259/p#comment990747_398259)). And there are even more awesome examples here on TeX.SX, but I am to lazy to search for them now.

Comment: @StefanPinnow, thank you for both links. i will analyse your answers and read manual again. so far i rarely use `\pgplotstable` (because my first impression was "very complicated" ... ; now it seems that i will change my mind :-) ).